# Codesigned application is crashing on reboot of Catalina with "EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)"

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, codesign

I've got an application that is codesigned properly that starts up and runs without issue -- unless/until some macs (in this case Catalina 10.15.5) reboot.

In this case the mac was shut down with power button so when it reboots it attempts to restart open apps. When it restarts my application I get the crash report below.

Restarting the app manually works, because it is properly signed. I just can't figure out what the problem is on boot - I have no information to go on as you can see.

Just to be clear on my architecture (in case it somehow matters): I have a parent application "Ggui" that runs a background service "GService". "Gservice" spins up an app that goes into a socket listen mode  - this is the app that is crashing. It is called "Vchat".

```
Ggui
  |_____ Gservice
  |           |______ Vchat
  |           |______ UpdateCheck
  |
  |_____ Dservice
```

Crash report:

```
Process:               Vchat [685]
Path:                      /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/Vchat.app/Contents/MacOS/Vchat
Identifier:            Vchat
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [521]
Responsible:           Ggui [431]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-08-17 09:55:32.890 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.5 (19F101)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     4.5 (17P5300)
Anonymous UUID:        2E8B1B09-530B-660E-2690-AE512687AE94


Time Awake Since Boot: 170 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        Unknown

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Killed: 9
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x9
Terminating Process:   Gservice [521]

kernel messages:

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x00007ffeeeee4b28
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15:     0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x0000000107d68000  rfl: 0x0000000000000200  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     0


Binary images description not available


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 144
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

Model: MacBookAir8,1, BootROM 1037.120.87.0.0 (iBridge: 17.16.15300.0.0,0), 2 processors,     Dual-Core Intel Core i5, 1.6 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 
Graphics: kHW_IntelUHDGraphics617Item, Intel UHD Graphics 617, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E435054414C42522D4E5644
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80AD,     0x483943434E4E4E435054414C42522D4E5644
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x843), wl0: Feb 28 2020     15:31:19 version 9.30.357.35.32.5.42 FWID 01-9d05982a
Bluetooth: Version 7.0.5f6, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Apple T2 Bus
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Headset
USB Device: Ambient Light Sensor
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Apple T2 Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 47.4
```

Comment: You may want to post this at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) instead of here.

Comment: When you say "[r]estarting the app manually works", do you mean Ggui? Or are you relaunching Vchat directly? Also, there may be clues in the system log. You can use the `log` command to examine it, but you're going to have to trawl through tons of irrelevant output to find something relevant.

Comment: I mean restarting the parent process "Ggui" after the reboot has "settled" then I get no crash and things work no problem. Thanks for the `log` command, I've never heard of it. And you're right `log show` has a TON of stuff in it.